# Calling Stored procedure EF6 & MVC from Inteface in the repository pattern EXAMPLE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures, repository-pattern

I am using MVC 5 and Entity Framework 6 Database First approach.

I cannot find an example of calling a stored procedure in the interface and the return type is another problem as for example:

My Select is as follows

```
Create Procedure pcdSELECTEMPLOYEE

@Del bit

AS

SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE @Del = EMPLOYEE.DEL

GO
```

Del is a flag field used for deleting in the database for best practice.

So, my get all or even get by ID involves this:

I have from EF a [GET/SET class] for employee
A context class that has the stored procedure

I need help with IRepository.cs and Repository.cs calling the `Context.pcdSELECTEMPLOYEE` or `Context.pcdSELECTEMPLOYEEBYID`

What objects do I set in the interphace for return types or anything?

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    // other CRUD methods here...
}
```

Please help this would be much appreciated

Thanks

Entity Framework creates the following 
 public virtual

```
ObjectResult<pcdSelectStaffBID_Result>pcdSelectStaffBID(Nullable<int> iD)
        {
            var iDParameter = iD.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("ID", iD) :
                new ObjectParameter("ID", typeof(int));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<pcdSelectStaffBID_Result>("pcdSelectStaffBID", iDParameter);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the repository pattern, then you'll have a UnitOfWork class. The calls to your stored procedures should be placed in the UnitOfWork class.

As for the return type, when you create the Function Import in Entity Framework, you can select the Employee class as the return type for each item in the collection that's returned by your stored procedure. The stored procedure return a collection of Employees.

If your stored procedure returned only a subset of the columns from the Employee table, then you would not be able to choose the Employee class. In that case, Entity Framework would create a Complex Type for you.

Comment: Please provide a example of calling the h complex type in a interface thanks

Comment: im not using the unit of work approach as with the bigger projects it causes restrictions essentually my ef6 is the unitofwork class

Answer (score 0):

You may create you own EFRepository class which implements IRepository, and in 
GetAll() do like this
`if( T.Gettype()=typeof(Employee)) {
_dbContext.SqlQuery<Employee>(sqltext, params).ToArray();
}`
You also can use attributes on Entities not to hard code :)

- I use `public IQueryable<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null)
      {
          return (predicate == null) ? _context.Set<T>() : _context.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
      }` to filter on db level